# Confused how to extract value from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
diction_a = {'x': {'zebra':'white', 'raptors':'bosh', 'teams' :  [{'a': 0, 'b': '123456', 'c': 1, 'd': 'xuix'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '234567', 'c': 1, 'd': 'lebron?', 'owner': 'heat'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '7890324', 'c': 1, 'd': 'durant'}, ..{many more with similar format}]
```

So I'm given diction_a as the dictionary but I need to extract the value of 'b' from 'teams' from multiple dictionaries within the list. I have this code below, but when I print list_of_b its an empty list.

```
search = diction_a ['x']['teams']
list_of_b = [a.get('b') for a in search if 'b' in a]
```

Comment: Please make a complete, minimal example ([click here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), your code seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm first your data structure is correct, here's a working example using exactly your code:

```
diction_a = {
    'x': {
        'zebra': 'white',
        'raptors': 'bosh',
        'teams':  [
            {
                'a': 0,
                'b': '123456',
                'c': 1,
                'd': 'xuix'
            }, {
                'a': 0,
                'b': '234567',
                'c': 1,
                'd': 'lebron?',
                'owner': 'heat'
            }, {
                'a': 0,
                'b': '7890324',
                'c': 1,
                'd': 'durant'
            }
        ]
    }
}


search = diction_a['x']['teams']
list_of_b = [a.get('b') for a in search if 'b' in a]
print list_of_b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print [val['b']  for x in diction_a.values() for val in  x['teams'] ]
```

Input :

```
diction_a = {'x': {'zebra':'white', 'raptors':'bosh','teams' :  [{'a': 0, 'b': '123456', 'c': 1, 'd': 'xuix'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '234567', 'c': 1, 'd': 'lebron?', 'owner': 'heat'},{'a': 0, 'b': '7890324', 'c': 1, 'd': 'durant'}] } }
```

Output :

```
['123456', '234567', '7890324']
```

Comment: When I run exactly what you have, I get this : <generator object <genexpr> at 0x105fc1678>

Comment: That because you use this code in own function, and when you call this function, you forget '()' after function's name,